# What statistical network allows to pick where to take the values from?

Tags: statistics, bayesian-network

I am looking for a mathematical framework similar to Bayesian Network that would allow me to solve next class of problems:

- Ann and Ron are running towards one of 2 closed baskets with apples.
- if in a basket there is an apple (we have a probability value for that) person can eat it
- we have a probability for Ann and Ron picking basket A or B, they can pick the same one.
- I want to know from which Ann would pick, and if there would be an apple in it?

Is it possible to solve via Bayesian Network or with what kind of network it is solvable?

Comment: The problem is that if Ron has picked basket A and there was only one apple when Ann gets to it there shall be 0 apples... and I can not help but wonder how to express such construct in mathematical/statistical graphs/terms?

Comment: And when Ann finds there is no apple in basket A she will try to pick from basket B